# multiple comma htaccess with ajax

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I use htaccess for pretty url...

But now, I don't understand why ajax request return "404 not found" with multiple parameter.

- url behind htaccess : delete.php?id=1,2,3,4 work perfectly

  url after htaccess : delete/1,2,3 but dont work (error 404)

Htaccess:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^delete/(\w+)$ ./delete.php?id=$1
```

and ajax code:

```
  $('#delete').click(function () {
   var Checkboxes = new Array();

   i = 0;
   $("li input:checked").each(function () {
       Checkboxes[i] = $(this).val();

       i++;
   });

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "delete/" + Checkboxes, //<-problem is here maybe problem with htaccess and multiple value?
       success: function (msg) {
           alert("Data deleted: " + msg);
       }
   });
```

});

But, i don't understand where is problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `\w`  (wordcharacter) in regex is a shortcut for `[a-z0-9A-Z_]` which does not contain commas. Thats why your rule does not match for `1,2,3` and you get a `404` error because of that.

If you change your rewrite rule from:

```
   RewriteRule ^delete/(\w+)$ ./delete.php?id=$1
```

to

```
   RewriteRule ^delete/([a-z0-9A-Z,]+)$ ./delete.php?id=$1
```

it should work.

Comment: if the `id`s are always only numbers you could just write `[0-9,]` instead of `[a-z0-9A-Z,]`  with that you will already limit the valid input.